# Symfony 6.1 reset-password php 8.1

Tags: symfony, bundle, reset-password, php-8.1

I am trying to install the Reset Password Feature on my symfony application.

The Problem is that **Composer tell me that** :

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

    Problem 1
        - php is present at version 8.1.0 and cannot be modified by Composer
        - symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle v1.16.0 conflicts with php >=8.1 <8.1.10.
        - Root composer.json requires symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle ^1.16 -> satisfiable 
          by symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle[v1.16.0-password-bundle[v1.16.0].
                                                                                                                                   
        You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint,
        e.g. "composer require symfonycasts/reset-password-buycasts/reset-password-bundle:*"
        to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require symfonycasts/e-paif 
        you know which yondle:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or 
        "composerreset-password-bundle:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

So, do I have to install a specific version ?

Comment: According to the bundle's `composer.json` it's not installable with php from 8.1.0 to 8.1.10. You can update your php version to 8.1.11 or downgrade it to an old 7.X https://github.com/SymfonyCasts/reset-password-bundle/blob/main/composer.json

Comment: "symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle v1.16.0 conflicts with php >=8.1 <8.1.10." - anything unclear about that? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [composer.json](https://github.com/SymfonyCasts/reset-password-bundle/blob/main/composer.json) of the Reset Password Bundle, you can see that there is a conflict with PHP version 8.1.0, 8.1.1, ... 8.1.10.

```yaml
    "conflict": {
        "php": ">=8.1 <8.1.10",
        "doctrine/orm": "<2.7"
    },
```

So, yes, you have to upgrade your stack to PHP version 8.1.11

[This pull request](https://github.com/SymfonyCasts/reset-password-bundle/pull/235) give explanations why this bundle is currently no more  compatible with these PHP versions.